# password view for all fields in a view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, model-view-controller

I am having a form which contains three fields with `PasswordFor` razor syntax.

Here is the link to the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM8Ph.png)
When I focus on field I can see the password when I click and hold an eye in that field.

I want to when I click an eye in each field to be able to see all three fields without asterix.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you excepting like this

```js
$(".reveal").on('click',function() {
    var $pwd = $(".pwd");
    if ($pwd.attr('type') === 'password') {
        $pwd.attr('type', 'text');
    } else {
        $pwd.attr('type', 'password');
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">    
  <div class="text-center">           
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Password show / hide click</h2> 
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control pwd" value="password">
          <input type="password" class="form-control pwd" value="password1">
          <input type="password" class="form-control pwd" value="password2" >     
       
      </div>     
        
               <button style="float:right;" class="btn btn-default reveal" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
        </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but I have for example in Chrome an eye built-in..how to remove that eye which is inside of a textbox?

Comment: i can't understand, could you please explain it clearly @Stefan0309

Comment: when you put `type='password' in a input, chrome, edge and other browsers, automatically adds an "eye" clickable icon in each textfield. Can I grab that event? ant to show all passwords from holding a mouse on that icon?Also, I need to change icon on event on hoilding a mouse

Comment: The eye icon can only be seen in IE and edge. The default eye icon in chrome is not yet introduced. I asked this question a few minutes ago.  Check for clarification.